# how to run location tracking service after screen is off?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, location

location can't update when screen is off.

How to run location tracking service after screen is off ?

I start service using

```
val serviceClass = ControlLocationService::class.java
val intent = Intent(activity, serviceClass)
activity?.startService(intent)
```

In onLocationChanged method I try Log.e()
but not show latitude and longitude in logcat when screen is off

```
class ControlLocationService : Service() {

    lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationCallback:LocationCallback

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
    }

    @SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag")
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        //service is started
        updateLocation()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun updateLocation() {
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                onLocationChanged(locationResult!!.lastLocation)
            }
        }
        buildLocationRequest()
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
    }

    private fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        Log.e("...", location.latitude.toString()+location.longitude.toString())
    }

    private fun buildLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 3000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 1000
        //locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 1f
    }


}
```

Help me introduce about service management when the screen is off. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a wakelock and I would also make your service foreground. This will make android less likely to kill your app or service. Actually according to [Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits) its not said that you need a wakelock - only foreground service. By making your app work continously in the background, you will make it quickly drain your user battery - which is bad. Consider using passive location updates, those might happen few time in a hour - which might not be what you are after.

You might also want to read about [doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#restrictions) which makes all non white-listed applications ignore wake locks while in screen off mode.

To add wake lock:

```
val mgr = service.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
val wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "myAppName:MyWakeLock")
wakeLock.acquire()
```

in `onDestroy`:

```
wakeLock.release()
```

Use below code to add notification to notification bar and make service foreground. You should add `addServiceNotification(this)` in your `onStartCommand`.

```
fun addServiceNotification(service: Service) {
    val mgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(service)
    val title = "Caption"
    val text = "Location"

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        val notificationManager = service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            var mChannel: NotificationChannel? = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "myAppName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
            }
        }

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(service, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build()

        service.startForeground(LOCATION_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        mgr.cancel(LOCATION_NOTIFICATION_ID)
        mgr.notify(LOCATION_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }
}

// remove notification for location service
fun removeServiceNotification(service: Service) {
  val notificationManager = service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
  notificationManager?.cancel(LOCATION_NOTIFICATION_ID)
}

companion object {
    val LOCATION_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1001
    val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "myAppName"
}
```